# Parsing multi-line string in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a string that looks like this:

```
TYPE Email Forwarding

SIGNATURE mysig.html

COMPANY Smith Incorp

CLIENT NAME James Henries

... heaps of others ....
```

I need to get the values of Type, Signature, Company and Client Name. There are others but once I can find a soution on how to do these, I can do the rest. I have tried to split and trim the string but then it splits fields like CLIENT NAME or on values like Email Forwarding.

Comment: try [.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please *ask a question*. A list of things you want isn't a question. Show us some code and ask a *specific* question *about that code*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put all of the "key" values into a collection, and then parse the string into another collection and then compare the values of the collections.

Here is a rough outline of how you could get the values:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Assuming that you know all of the keys before hand
        List<string> keys = new List<string>() { "TYPE", "SIGNATURE", "COMPANY", "CLIENT NAME" };

        //Not sure of the origin of your string to parse.  You would have to change
        //this to read a file or query the DB or whatever
        string multilineString =
            @"TYPE Email Forwarding

            SIGNATURE mysig.html

            COMPANY Smith Incorp

            CLIENT NAME James Henries";

        //Split the string by newlines.
        var lines = multilineString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //Iterate over keys because you probably have less keys than data in the event of duplicates
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            //Reduce list of lines to check based on ones that start with a given key
            var filteredLines = lines.Where(l => l.Trim().StartsWith(key)).ToList();

            foreach (var line in filteredLines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line.Trim().Remove(0, key.Length + 1));
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That will do your job.

If it is multiple lines then you can loop through each line and call KeyValue extension method as given below:

```
 public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var value = "TYPE Email Forwarding".KeyValue();
            var value1 = "CLIENT NAME James Henries".KeyValue();

        }

        public static KeyValuePair<string, string> KeyValue(this string rawData)
        {
            var splitValue = rawData.Split(new[] { ' ' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            KeyValuePair<string, string> returnValue;

            var key = string.Empty;
            var value = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in splitValue)
            {
                if (item.ToUpper() == item)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
                    {
                        key += item;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        key += " " + item;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    {
                        value += item;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value += " "  + item;
                    }
                }
            }

            returnValue = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

Please note that this logic will work only when keys are all upper and the values are not all upper case. Otherwise, there is no way to identify which one is key (without having a manual track on keys) and which one is not.